# Flutter - How to enable AnimatedOpacity automatically?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm creating a dashboard which contain Tween animation for two widgets, Text and two Container. But, I want to make the two Container's opacity changing slowly from invisible to visible...so I used AnimatedOpacity. But I don't know how to do it...

***Any help would be appreciated..***

```
class _IntroState extends State<Intro> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation animation;
  AnimationController animationController;

   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
      animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        vsync: this,
     );

    animation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _visible = false;
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

  return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
         return Scaffold(
           //BODDY
            body: ListView(
              hildren:<Widget>[
                 new Stack(
                   children: <Widget>[
                     new Transform(
                       //ANIMATED OPACITY
                       new AnimatedOpacity(
                          opacity: _visible ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          child: new Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 12.0),
                            child: new Row(
                               children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                   child: Row(
                                     children: <Widget>[
                                       child: Padding(
                                         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                //THIS THE CONTAINER
                                                new Container(. . .),
                                                new Container(. . .)
```

Comment: `_visible` should be a field of your state. and you should `setState`.

Comment: is setState can be used without onTap or GestureDetector?

Comment: sure you can, it's a simple method that can be called anytime you want. I would put the _visible to state and change its value in initState.

Comment: if you change `_visible` in `initState`, there will be no "fade in" animation.

Comment: you are right, I meant the setState, as mentioned by Remi above. But while I was reading the code, I got confused and wrote initState. Human mistake :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of `AnimatedOpacity`, use a `FadeTransition` widget. This gives you manual control over the animation:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animationController.drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut)),
      child: ...,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

To make a `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget` fade in automatically on creation, `TweenAnimationBuilder` provides an even easier solution:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
        curve: Curves.ease,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        builder: (BuildContext context, double opacity, Widget? child) {
          return Opacity(
              opacity: opacity,
              child: Container(width: 20, height: 20, color: Colors.red)
          );
    });
  }
}
```

See my Codepen for a complete example: https://codepen.io/atok/pen/BaZVRPr

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who'd like to fade a widget automatically as soon as the page is rendered and still wants to use `AnimatedOpacity`, you can put the call to change the state of the opacity in the WidgetsBinding's [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) callback.

Put this code below in your `initState`.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    setState(() {
        _opacity = 1;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

***I totally recommend using @boformer 's answer above.***

But, I played around with your code and wanted to show you how you can call setState to trigger the `AnimatedOpacity`, so you can see that it is working without `onTap` or `GestureDetector` as you were thinking in the comments above.

I got your code and played around with it. What I did is, simply added a status listener to your animation controller and when the controller is done. I triggered the visibility boolean in `setState`. Then it will change the visibility of the containers.

```
// When animation finished change the visibility.
animationController.addStatusListener((status){
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    setState(() {
      // This is opposite, because it's implemented opposite in your code.
      _visible = false;
    });
  }
});
```